# How can I keep url parameter from page to page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-ads-api

How can I keep google's ads gclid parameter when the visitor goes from one page to another?

E.g. The visitor comes from google with the paramenter and lands on page a (www.example.com/a/?gclid=abcd123) 
When he goes on a another page (www.example.com/b) the parameter should be kept as so (www.example.com/b/?gclid=abcd123)

ps on wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain query params across website using [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/).

#### Steps

1. Create custom variables on GTM which you need to pass on to each link into your website.
2. Add below javascript code in GTM to fetch custom param from link and add it to url.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var utmInheritingDomain = "yourdomain.com", // REPLACE THIS DOMAIN 
      utmRegExp = /(\&|\?)utm_[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+/gi,
      links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
      utms = [
        "gclid={{URL - gclid}}" // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE gclid
      ];

    for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index += 1) {
      var tempLink = links[index].href,
        tempParts;

      if (tempLink.indexOf(utmInheritingDomain) > 0) { // The script is looking for all links with the gclid
        tempLink = tempLink.replace(utmRegExp, "");

        tempParts = tempLink.split("#");

        if (tempParts[0].indexOf("?") < 0) {
          tempParts[0] += "?" + utms.join("&"); // The script adds gclid parameter to all links with the domain you've defined
        } else {
          tempParts[0] += "&" + utms.join("&");
        }

        tempLink = tempParts.join("#");
      }

      links[index].href = tempLink;
    }
  }());
</script>
```

You can find detailed steps [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/#gref)